# X11 forward display from docker container to a non-host display

Tags: docker, x11-forwarding

Host A - Remote Linux server ( No GUI )
Host B - Remote Windows ( GUI )
Host C - Remote Windows ( GUI )

Scenario: Using Putty on Host B and XMing and setting X11 forwarding to `:0.0` and ssh to Host A; next, open any visual editor -> UI successfully displays on Host B.

Running a docker container with X11 forwarding also sends the display to Host B when supplying the env DISPLAY=Host-B-IP and /tmp/.X11-unix volume.

Now, on Host C with XMing, ssh via putty similarly to Host A and open a visual editor; this displays on Host C as expected.

**The problem part:** I'd like to run a docker container from Host A to use the display of Host C (which fails/timesout).

Note: Whether I run the container when connecting from either Host B or C doesn't display despite setting the docker env DISPLAY to Host-C-IP. However, if use the IP of Host B, it displays on B successfully in both cases.